# Wrong loop cuts position offered by blender by default

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I'm making the arms of my bird, and I need to place some loop cuts in a specific area to match the topology of the arm with that of the body.

The problem is that Blender offers to place the loop cuts in totally wrong places! Can you explain how I can place them where I want?

I attached 2 screenshots:

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Or, if Blender offers the chance to correctly place the loop cut, I can't use it because it breaks the mesh, like here:

[image]

...and here: (it seems it creates a series of vertices under the existing ones without care about the actual topology):

[image: 3]

Since I haven't been able to make people understand what I mean, I am trying again by attaching 3 new pictures to the post.

On the first picture you can see that there are 3 starting loopcuts. The circled one is correctly attached to the end of the arm while the other ones aren't.

[image: 5]

On the second picture you can see that at the end of the arm, there is the need to make two loop cuts that should be attached to those you have seen on the previous picture.

[image: 6]

on the third picture you can see the loop cut proposed by Blender; that's not right for my needs.

[image: 7]

So, how can I make the right loopcuts without too much effort? Thanks. Also, I've attached the .blend file of the bird:

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking, what do you mean the position of loopcut is wrong? Could you clarify? By default a loopcut is always placed at the center, equal distance between both adjacent edge loops. After you make the first mouse click you will have the chance to slide it to the desired position, and click again to confirm. If you are still not satisfied with the loopcut position you can still use edge slide afterwards to adjust it.

Comment: I suggest marking on the screenshots where you think the loops cuts should be placed.

Comment: I edited the question,to make it more clear.

Comment: @Marietto Note that there are some inverted normals shenanigans going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop cuts not going all the way around would be the result of the loop cut running into a face that has more or less than 4 sides; an **n-gon**.

To make a loop cut go in the direction you want, make sure to place your cursor on an edge perpendicular to the direction of the loopcut (cursor is where *3D Cursor* is):

[image]

[image]

These are the basic principles for all loop cut making.

Comment: I edited the question,to make it more clear.